# In which cases can SVM totally fail but Decision trees/Multilayer Perceptrons succeed in classification?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, svm, cart, accuracy

I have been working with a binary classification problem recently. The dataset contained 20 features.

I used SVM with different parameter settings and got 50% accuracy (i.e. all predictions are belonging to the same class). But when I used a decision tree, the accuracy was near 85%. I achieved almost the same accuracy using MLP.

For what kinds of data might this happen?

Comment: It can happen if many of your features are irrelevant -- most SVM formulations assume that only relevant features are included.

Comment: @Sycorax do you have any reference or just personal experience?

Comment: The effect of Irrelevant features is examined in the SVM chapter of Elements of Statistical Learning.